# correct javascript syntax for two or more strings in operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this piece of code, but I am not getting my syntax correct.  I tried it several ways.  The first one below seems like it should work, but I am not quite there yet.  Please point me in the correct direction for what the correct syntax is when comparing multiple strings

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var url = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
if ( [ 'page_id=11', 'page_id=19'].indexOf( url ) > -1 ) { 
$('#main').css("background-color","#ebecee"); 
}
});
```

and I also tried like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var url = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
if(url.href.indexOf("page_id=11") > -1 && ("page_id=19") > -1 ) {
$('#main').css("background-color","#ebecee");
}
});
```

What is the correct way to write it?

Comment: There are many "correct" ways to write it. The problem is probably that your URL doesn't contain the value you think it contains. Try `console.log(url)`.

Answer (score 1):

"A shot in the dark"

Part of the problem may be that you're looking at `window.location.pathname` and in most cases something like `page_id=19` is not part of the *pathname* -- it is part of the **query**.

Look at `window.location.search` instead to check *just* the query parameters, or, as the others suggested, look at the entire location by checking `window.location.href` or `document.URL`.

```
var query = window.location.search;
if (query.indexOf("page_id=11") > -1 || query.indexOf("page_id=19) > -1) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks the window.location.search was a great suggestion

Comment: I up voted your answer, this is the correct one, for the life of me I couldn't remember `window.location.search` when I answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to check if either `page_id=11` or `page_id=19` is in your page's URL, this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(document.URL.indexOf("page_id=11") > -1 || document.URL.href.indexOf("page_id=19") > -1 ) {
        $('#main').css("background-color","#ebecee");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = location.href;
if(url.indexOf("page_id=11") > -1 || url.indexOf("page_id=19") > -1 ) {
    $('#main').css("background-color","#ebecee");
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked I also added window.location.search.substring(1);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localeCompare()` method.

This method returns a number indicating whether a reference string comes before or after or is the same as the given string in sort order.

Syntax:

```
string.localeCompare( param )
```

Return Value:

- 0 : It string matches 100%.
- 1 : no match, and the parameter value comes before the string object's value in the locale sort order
- -1 : no match, and the parameter value comes after the string object's value in the locale sort order

Your case

```
var index1 = location.href.localeCompare( "page_id=11" );
var index2 = location.href.localeCompare( "page_id=19" );
```

[More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)